Run QGIS python library in FME
I would like to run scripts that use QGIS libraries but I am unable to do that. I followed instructions in documentation of FME but it does not help... I always get error: The User-specified library C:\Users\fa08119\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Qgis-env\python312.dll could not be loaded
My environment setup: C:\Users\fa08119\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\qgis-env-py311\python311.dll.
Thanks!
I tried to verify if my Qgis environment made in anaconda has Qgis module, and it does. I have tried to point my interpreter to QGIS default python env. I also tried different versions of python. Non helps.

Do not include images to add text informations: please copy the text and put in the question. If you want help, you should try to help us. -- Note: me as many people will not open random links from random people.
